# Problem while running pod init: "Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built."

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal, cocoapods

While running pod init on my Xcode Project, I come across a problem in the terminal with the following message:

```
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:128:in `git_version': Failed to extract git version from `git --version` ("xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun\n") (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:140:in `verify_minimum_git_version!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

"

I've tried running gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0" and that gives me the following

```
message: "Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

If you have any suggestions please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Try running it with sudo

Comment: @cora I tried running sudo gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0 and it still gave me a lot of messages relating the same thing, like: "its extensions are not built.", "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Ext::BuildError)
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.", "extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.".

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Comment: Just look around, this error is not new.

Comment: @cora I've tried something from the link you sent me, I guess it removed one of my errors but still got another. after i run pod init it gives me this message: "Could not find 'ffi' (>= 1.15.0) among 85 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/christian/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
"